# ChromeDriver / webDriver Sharing Session

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to do selenium Tests.
I could use the chrome, Firefox, opera driver (I prefer chrome).

If I log into my account on the targeted website with the selenium webdriver, the website tells the normal chrome browser that I got kicked from the session.

Is there a way to avoid this problem?

Comment: The site probably only allows a single session per user so it's booting out the old session every time you log on. The only way around it is to have a whole bunch of different accounts for testing or have the devs allow the test account to have multiple sessions - with a session timeout so you don't use up all your sessions.

Comment: I could solve it (kinda) with using the same session as chrome does default. But you have to close chrome on every driver init